# JPA find() works, persist no exceptions no results, remove shows query and throw Removing a detached instance exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I don't know what should I add to make it works.
Here is my Entity class:

```
@Entity
public class Student {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;
private String name;
private int age;

//setters and getters
}
```

my application-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="orm" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="wisla666"/>
</bean>

<bean id="myEmf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="orm.entity" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        </bean>     
    </property> 
</bean>

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEmf" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
```

and this is my Dao class:

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import orm.entity.Student;

@Repository
public class StudentDaoImpl implements StudentDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public Student loadStudent(int id) {
        return entityManager.find(Student.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    public void saveStudent(Student student) {
        entityManager.persist(student);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteStudent(Student student) {
        entityManager.remove(entityManager.merge(student));
    }
}
```

First I load Student object from DB and it works and then I try to remove this object from DB and it doesn't work. During removing the sql syntax is visible:

```
Hibernate: select student0_.id as id1_0_0_, student0_.age as age2_0_0_, student0_.name as name3_0_0_ from Student student0_ where student0_.id=?
```

and an exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Removing a detached instance orm.entity.Student#2
```

During persisting Student object nothing happens.

The question is what can I do to make it works?

Answer (score 1):

the code:

```
@Repository
public class StudentDaoImpl implements StudentDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public Student loadStudent(int id) {
        return entityManager.find(Student.class, id);
    }
}
```

the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
     StudentServiceImpl ssi = context.getBean("studentServiceImpl", StudentServiceImpl.class);
}
```

the exception: Error creating bean with name 'studentServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed

here is my question: if @Transactional can't be with the same plce as @PersistenceContext? Why can't I assign this bean?

Comment: @Transactional can be in the same place as @PersistenceContext. I think you are just trying to get bean in a wrong way. Try ```StudentService studentService = context.getBean(StudentService.class)```.

Answer (score 0):

Once you call `loadStudent(int id)`, the returned `Student` entity is detached - means no longer attached to hibernate Session.

As it is no longer in session, it is not possible to perform remove operation. To solve the problem, you can wrap your call in transactional method, so that find and remove operations will be performed in one transaction.

Assuming you have `StudentService`, you can have something like

```
@Service
public StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService {

     @Autowired
     private StudentDao studentDao;

     @Transactional
     public void remove(int id) {
           Student student = studentDao.loadStudent(id);
           studentDao.remove(student);
     }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works ;) The last question is:
 If I add @Transactional annotation over some method in my StudentDaoImpl class the app-context.xml can't assign bean to my obj in main method. Why?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't understand the question. Can you please share a code you  are trying? Basically you can add @Transactional to your StudentDaoImpl, but it is strongly not advised to do. You should make your services instead transactional, where your business logic lies on.